# Sub menu items appearing on bottom bar and not within the flyout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a sub menu under my flyout but its placing it on the bottom bar instead for some reason.

```
addonsflayout.Items.Add(new ShellContent {
            Title = "Airliners",
            Icon = "tab_about",
            Content = new AboutPage()
});

addonsflayout.Items.Add(new ShellContent    {
            Title = "Piston Planes",
            Icon = "tab_about",
            Content = new AboutPage()
});
addonsflayout.Items.Add(new ShellContent    {
            Title = "Turbo Props",
            Icon = "tab_about",
            Content = new AboutPage()
        });
```

My Main shell flyouts are describe as such

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Addons" x:Name="addonsflayout" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent Route="AddonsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AddonsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

<!-- When the Flyout is visible this will be a menu item you can tie a click behavior to  -->
<MenuItem Text="Logout" StyleClass="MenuItemLayoutStyle" Clicked="OnMenuItemClicked">
</MenuItem>
```

But its placing them in the bottom bar so it is.
[image]

When I want them here

[image]

How does one tell it to show for the side menu and not the bottom bar I am using xamrain forms

**Edit 2**
While adding  FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" does get it to appear its also adding it to the bottom bar and without indentition in the side menu

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Addons"  FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" x:Name="addonsflayout" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent Route="AddonsPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AddonsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Piston planes should be further in. Also doing this has removed my main menu item addons.

[image]

Comment: You could check this similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468775/in-xamarin-forms-shell-how-do-i-add-menuitems-programatically .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT if u look at my code that exaclty what i have tried

Comment: What is the version of the XF in your project . I used the above code and it works fine .

Comment: The very lattest 5.0.0.1829-pre6 aprenlty its a issue with shell and documented on msfs web site i submitted it as a bug as this should work